# Weighted Random Sampling

Tags: probability

Suppose I have to distribute 2 gold bars to 3 people. The independent probabilities of each person getting a bar is 90%, 60%, and 50%. Each person only gets 1 bar or no bar at all. 2 people will get a bar and 1 person will not get a bar.

How can I use a random number generator to distribute the bars accordingly?

I am currently working on creating a game and want to implement something like this. Just don't know where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your wording of the problem is incorrect. As you wrote it, it is possible for none of the people to get a bar, and it is possible for all three of them to get a bar.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the wording to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is not clearly stated. In particular, it is not clear as to what the "independent probabilities" stand for in the context of distributing gold bars to person. As such, the answer hinges on the interpretation.

Let me present an answer based on the interpretation that each "independent probability" means the probability of a person ending up getting a gold bar after the bars has been distributed.

1. Let $A_i$ be the event that person $i$ gets a gold bar, $i = 1, 2, 3$. Then they satisfy $\mathbf{P}(A_1) = 0.9$, $\mathbf{P}(A_2) = 0.6$, $\mathbf{P}(A_3) = 0.5$.
2. Let $E_i$ be the event that person $i$ doesn't get a bar. Then exactly one of $E_1$, $E_2$, or $E_3$ occurs.

Then $A_1$ is a disjoint union of $E_2$ and $E_3$ and hence

$$ \mathbf{P}(E_2) + \mathbf{P}(E_3) = \mathbf{P}(A_1) = 0.9. \tag{1} $$

Likewise,

$$ \mathbf{P}(E_1) + \mathbf{P}(E_3) = \mathbf{P}(A_2) = 0.6 \tag{2} $$

and

$$ \mathbf{P}(E_1) + \mathbf{P}(E_2) = \mathbf{P}(A_3) = 0.5 \tag{3} $$

Note that, if we sum the three equalities $\text{(1)–(3)}$, we get

$$ 2(\mathbf{P}(E_1) + \mathbf{P}(E_2) + \mathbf{P}(E_3)) = 0.9 + 0.6 + 0.5 = 2, $$

which is consistent with the equality $\mathbf{P}(E_1) + \mathbf{P}(E_2) + \mathbf{P}(E_3) = 1$ coming from Item 2. (In general, under the above interpretation, the problem makes sense only if $\sum_i \mathbf{P}(A_i)$ is equal to the number of people who gets a gold bar.)

Now solving the system $\text{(1)–(3)}$, we get

$$ \mathbf{P}(E_1) = 0.1, \qquad \mathbf{P}(E_2) = 0.4, \qquad \mathbf{P}(E_3) = 0.5 $$

and all you have to do is simulate this categorical distribution. That is,

1. Simulate a random number generate that picks a number $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$ with probability $\mathbf{P}(E_i)$.
2. For that chosen number $i$, realize the scenario $E_i$ by giving the gold bars to people except for person $i$.

Comment: @JRN, Thank you, it is fixed now :)

Comment: Your solution is more elegant than mine. I'm ashamed I didn't think of it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Call the people $A$, $B$, and $C$. Let the situation be composed of two steps: First, give the first gold bar. Second, give the second gold bar.

For step 1, let the probability of the first gold bar going to person $A$ be $P(F_A)=\frac{90}{90+60+50}=0.45$. Let $P(F_B)=\frac{60}{90+60+50}=0.30$ and $P(F_C)=\frac{50}{90+60+50}=0.25$. The bar is now given to one of the three people.

For step 2, there are three possibilities: step 2A (where the first bar was given to person $A$), step 2B, and step 2C.

For step 2A, let the probability of the second gold bar going to person $B$ be $P(S_B|F_A)=\frac{60}{60+50}=\frac{6}{11}$. Let $P(S_C|F_A)=\frac{50}{60+50}=\frac{5}{11}$.

For step 2B, $P(S_A|F_B)=\frac{90}{90+50}=\frac{9}{14}$ and $P(S_C|F_B)=\frac{50}{90+50}=\frac{5}{14}$.

For step 2C, $P(S_A|F_C)=\frac{90}{90+60}=0.6$ and $P(S_B|F_C)=\frac{60}{90+60}=0.4$.

I hope this is enough to help you.